# Objects appear in the viewport and preview render, but not in the outliner or final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I don't understand what happened. Before when I saved the file it worked fine, but when I came back and reopened it, this problem started happening. (It is most visible with the character's eyes.)

[image]

The object is visible in the viewport, but it appears nowhere in the outliner. (Yes, I have scrolled down through the entire outliner to check.)
The objects even appear in the preview render and work fine there,(Sorry I couldn't post more than 2 pictures.) but once I press F12 for the final render the objects completely disappear.

[image]

I am using cycles render. I am hoping someone might be able to help me, I have searched a lot, but have not been able to find an answer to my problem anywhere.

Comment: could you post your file?

I'd say most probably they are in the outliner, they may be a child of another object, you may have disabled their render visibility, or they may have an invisible material? there are a couple of possible problems.

Comment: Most likely the missing objects are parented to another object and they are hidden in the outliner, uncollapse the objects one by one (using the + icons to the left of objects) and find if an object within the hierarchy has the eye icon enabled but not the camera one.

Comment: The triangle symbol in the outliner besides the armature tells me that mesh geometry is attached to it. Expand the armature hierarchy. And i guess you will find your eye geometry. Your eye geometry is either excluded from rendering. Or has no proper material assigned.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you most likely have the eyes set as not visible in the render. This is shown in the outliner with the camera to the right of the object, the eye is for viewport visibility, which also effects viewport preview rendering while the camera only affects the final render.

To find an item in the outliner you have a few options, if they are named well you can search for them -

[image: outliner search]

If you haven't named things, you can select it in the viewport and the item will be highlighted in the outliner, with a large list of items press <kbd>.</kbd> with the mouse over the outliner to zoom to the item, this will expand any parent objects to show the item.

[image: outliner items]

Once you locate the object in the outliner, click the camera to make it visible in the render.